# where can I find/modify the default precision of mysql floats?

Tags: mysql, ebean

I ran into an issue where it seems that mysql 5.1.63 (on a debian) stores 2/3 as
`0.666666666666667` and on mysql 5.5.21 (on a mac) as
`0.6666666666666667`

as I happen to use [Ebean](http://www.avaje.org/) to manage my database interactions, I need the mysql DOUBLE representation to correspond to the java `double` representation. (Otherwise Ebean will throw an `OptimisticLockException` as the java `double` representation can't be found in the mysql table)

As Ebean is generating the `create table` syntax for me and generates DOUBLE fields (no DECIMALs unfortunately), I was curious whether there is some setting to tell mysql which precision to use when a DOUBLE is defined without an explicit precision setting.

If you have other hints as to how resolve this issue, they are more than welcome as well.

Cheers, Daniel

Comment: Actually it doesn't store either `0.666666666666667` or `0.666666666666667` because `DOUBLE` is a binary floating point type, and neither of those values can be represented exactly as a double.

Comment: sorry for being imprecise here. "store" should probably say "represent", as those are the values that the mysql console displays after a SELECT query. Anyhow, I assume that those differing representations indicate a different precision, right?